# Laravel crud decimal change dot to comma in the form

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a **CRUD application**, and in the `Registrations` table there is a price with a decimal that can be with a **dot** or a **comma**.

1: i want a validation for a decimal that it accepts dots and commas. for examlple: (9,50 0,50 0.50 9.50)

2:
What i want is because the database stores the prices with dots, i want when i try to edit the record in my application it shows the price but it replaces the dot with a comma.

I think i have to use the `str_replace` function. But i dont know where to use it. Because in the controller i already use `str_replace` to save it with a dot in the database. Maybe in the html form with jquery?

Any help would be much appriciated!

Comment: use it in controller and parse it there before passing it to the view

Answer (score 5):

You may have a look at accessors: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Then just define the accessor in your model:

```
    public function getPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        return str_replace('.', ',', $value);
    }
```

You may define a mutator to make sure the price is always stored with a dot, even if user uses a comma:

```
    public function setPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['price'] = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }
```

Now, each time you display the price with `$registration->price` it will be displayed with a comma, no matter where you use it (any controller, blade template, whatever).

And when assigning the price a value, if it contains a comma, it will be replaced by a dot, no matter where you set it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i have one question: where do i put the second lines of code? I do have the first part in the controller where i save it. Not sure where to change the dot to comma though.

Comment: These lines of code go in the model. See the documentation link I've posted in the answer ;) The first one is called when you try to get the dynamic property `price` on the model: `$registration->price`. The property `price` actually does not exist, it's stored in `attributes` array property and accessed via magical `__get()`, which calls `getPriceAttribute()` when you want to get the price with `$registration->price`. The second is the same, but used when you set the value (it actually uses `__set()`)

Answer (score 1):

if i get you well.I think number_format function will help you with this problem.

```
$num = 1999.9;
$formattedNum = number_format($num);
echo $formattedNum;
  // this will return 2,000
$formattedNum = number_format($num, 2);
echo $formattedNum;
  //this will  return 1,999.90
```

However, in you instance, you can use the follow code

```
number_format($registration->price,2)
```

It will return the figure with two decimal places.
Hope it helps. You can read more on the following link https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp